getting an empty folder in django new project
I created a virtual environment than I installed Django successfully but when I try to create a project with Django-admin start-project project-name Django create an empty folder?
I'm expecting a folder with file with manage.py in the folder

try to deactivate the venv, delete that particular venv then create another Venv and install your dependencies

You have an error in the command you ran. You ran Django-admin start-project project-name but the correct command is:
django-admin startproject projectname .

Don't forget to add the period . it is important because it tells the script to install Django in your current directory.
Also do this in your active virtual environment. See How to create a Django project?.
